# React-router: is there a way to use push from history to append a query string after this current path?

Tags: javascript, html, react-router, html5-history

my current URL is `/foo` and I want to add a query string to it i.e.  `/foo?date=2022-02-15`

The way I did is `location.search = queryString` and it works but it results in a full reload. I wanted to use History API from `react-router` so I can avoid the full reload.

But `history.push` is going to replace the whole path `/foo` with `date=2022-02-15` (so the URL is going to be `date=2022-02-15`  as opposed to `/foo?date=2022-02-15`) as it doesn't append `?date=2022-02-15` to the current path `/foo` like `location.search` would do. So is there a way to use `history` API to achieve the same behavior?

Comment: Is `history.push("/foo?date=2022-02-15")` not sufficient? Can you include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for what you are trying to do?

Comment: @DrewReese how do I get the current path from history API?

Comment: You can get the current `pathname` from the `location` object of the current route being matched and rendered.

Comment: @DrewReese got it so like I have to first get that from `location` and then construct a string and use that with `push` from `history` like `push(`${pathname}?${queryString}`)` right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the current `pathname` from the `location` object of the current route being matched and rendered.

Example:

```
const location = useRouteMatch();
const queryString = "date=2022-02-15";

...

// as a string
history.push(`${location.pathname}?${queryString}`);

// or as an object
history.push({
  pathname: location.pathname,
  search: `?${queryString}`,
});
```